# My CSS stops working when I try use use the HTML5 tag

Tags: css, html

My CSS style stops working when I put the tag `<!DOCTYPE html>` to use HTML5. I used divs to separate the different styles in my pages, and used IDs to identify each one on the CSS code. Everything works fine but when I use that tag, it stops working. Anyone can help with this? Thank you!

Comment: please add some sample code

Comment: you have to post your code in order to get help here...

Comment: Can you share a link to your project, or your code, so we can reproduce it?

Comment: What does *"stops working"* mean?

Comment: For example:
`<div id = "thumbnail">
        <img src = "image.jpg">
  </div> `

And on the CSS file, I did something like this:

`#thumbnail{
width:270;
height:200;
text-align:left;

 }    `
Those parameters are applied to everything inside that divs, the size and alignment, but when I use the HTML5 tag, it stops working.

Comment: _more_ code: if possible, the complete HTML and CSS

Answer (score 1):

you did not use the "px" unit in the code you posted, like `width:270px;` Changing/completing this should help.